# A question about Lang's proof of simplicity of $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

> Theorem 5.5. If $n\geq 5$ then the alternating group $A_n$ is simple.
>
> Proof. Let $N$ be a non-trivial normal subgroup of $A_n$. We prove
>   that $N$ contains some $3$-cycle, whence the theorem follows by (b).
>   **Let $\sigma\in N$, $\sigma\ne id$, be an element which has the maximal number of fixed points**...

I don't understand why the highlighted part holds: why should such an element exist? Can someone describe the set which $\sigma$ supposedly belongs to in set-builder notation?

Comment: This is a finite problem.  No element (other than the identity) can fix more than $n$ elements, so you can ask for an element which fixes $n-1$ and on down the line.

Comment: Order $N$ by the number of fixed points. Since the set $N-\{\mathrm{id}\}$ is finite, every chain admits an upper bound. By Zorn's lemma, $N-\{\mathrm{id}\}$ contains at least $1$ maximal element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $s \in N$, let $\mathrm{fp}: N \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, taking $s$ to its number of fixed points.  Since $n$ is finite, $\mathrm{fp}(s)$ is finite for each $s \in N$.  Since $A_n$ is finite, $N$ is finite, so $M = \max \{\mathrm{fp}(s) : s \in N \smallsetminus \{\mathrm{id}\}\}$ exists.  Take $\sigma \in \{s \in N : \mathrm{fp}(s) = M\}$.

Comment: Maybe $\mathrm{id}$ need to be excluded from $N$?

Comment: @Learning.  Yeah, I suppose so.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of fixed points is at most $n-2$.
 So an element of $\{0,1,\dots,n-2\}$.  So just take an element of $N$ with the maximal number of fixed points.